# How do I automatically prefix all types/functions that go out of scope when removing "using namespace"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I have working C++ code opened in Visual Studio 2013. It uses a namespace I no longer want it to use (in this case, cv, so there is a line "using namespace cv;").

I have removed the line, and of course all types/functions in the cv namespace are no longer available, and to use them again they must be prefixed with "cv::".

My current method for resolving this is visually scanning the code for the Visual Studio red-squiggle-underline indicating an error, and pasting "cv::" in front of the offending type/function.

This is silly, since obviously my IDE already knows all of the locations that need to be prefixed (since they are the only ones being highlighted with the red squiggles; I'm basically manually performing 'find first incomplete/undefined type, and prefix with "cv::"'). Is there a straightforward way for me to leverage this information to make this tedious process automated?

Comment: how can the editor "know"? why should the editor assume that the function is from `namespace std`?

Comment: @vsoftco: In this case, `namespace cv`, not that it makes much difference.

Comment: You could probably make an editor macro for that. Something like "Jump to the next error, type `cv::`".

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks, swapped `std` with `cv`

Comment: @vsoftco: Because *I* know, and there is certainly some way for me to communicate this information to *some* editor, I was wondering if VS2013 had some way to do that; perhaps using a macro like Anton Savin suggested.

Comment: The macro system of vs2013 was much reduced from previous versions, as users who sent usage stats to MS did not use it enough or somesuch.  So I am doubtful.  Using command line compile and output parse and text edit with some scripting language might be doable.

Comment: maybe you do not have to fix every instance of cv::Mat, but can use `using cv::Mat;` instead